# React, в чем разница <div> и <>?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

Можете объяснить, в чем разница в React двух записей?

```
return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello</h1>
    <div/>
  );
```

```
return (
    <>
      <h1>Hello</h1>
    </>
  );
```

Comment: `<>…</>` — это сокращенный синтаксис для создания пустого родительского элемента

Comment: @DiMithras то есть нет разницы между ними, если не использовать стили?

Comment: Небольшая разница, всё же есть, во втором варианте не создаётся дополнительный DOM-узел. Т.е. помимо сокращения так вы явно указываете, что не хотите, чтобы там было что-то что может повлиять на вёрстку и стили.

Comment: @DiMithras огромное спасибо за объяснения!